# About the efficiency of re:run with "dotall" option?

Tags: regex, erlang

When i use `re:run`, i find an interesting thing: the efficiency is very low when i use `dotall` option.

The source code:

```
main3() ->
    Sdp = 
"v=0\r\no=- 1001 11112 IN IP4 10.10.121.7\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\nm=audio 52363 RTP/AVPF 0 8\r\nc=IN IP4 10.10.121.7\r\na=rtcp:52369 IN IP4 138.85.151.208\r\na=candidate:1783138469 1 udp 2113937151 138.85.151.208 52363 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:4012290674 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.125.1 52364 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:1760259326 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.2.12 52367 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:2294684747 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.58.1 52368 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:1783138469 2 udp 2113937150 138.85.151.208 52369 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:4012290674 2 udp 2113937150 192.168.125.1 52370 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:1760259326 2 udp 2113937150 192.168.2.12 52371 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:2294684747 2 udp 2113937150 192.168.58.1 52372 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:617313365 1 tcp 1509957375 138.85.151.208 52530 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:2711965314 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.125.1 52531 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:644386830 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.2.12 52532 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:3326468283 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.58.1 52533 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:617313365 2 tcp 1509957374 138.85.151.208 52534 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:2711965314 2 tcp 1509957374 192.168.125.1 52535 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:644386830 2 tcp 1509957374 192.168.2.12 52536 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:3326468283 2 tcp 1509957374 192.168.58.1 52537 typ host generation 0\r\na=ice-ufrag:root\r\na=ice-pwd:myreallysecretpassword\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=ssrc:1947760130 cname:OCGE4NpwFpLE/BFW\r\na=ssrc:1947760130 mslabel:oBAkRgSOpLdfl7u1JWdnMyUytcGGD4COvttP\r\na=ssrc:1947760130 label:oBAkRgSOpLdfl7u1JWdnMyUytcGGD4COvttP00\r\nm=video 52373 RTP/AVPF 126\r\nc=IN IP4 10.10.121.7\r\na=rtcp:52377 IN IP4 138.85.151.208\r\na=candidate:1783138469 1 udp 2113937151 138.85.151.208 52373 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:4012290674 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.125.1 52374 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:1760259326 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.2.12 52375 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:2294684747 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.58.1 52376 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:1783138469 2 udp 2113937150 138.85.151.208 52377 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:4012290674 2 udp 2113937150 192.168.125.1 52378 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:1760259326 2 udp 2113937150 192.168.2.12 52379 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:2294684747 2 udp 2113937150 192.168.58.1 52380 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:617313365 1 tcp 1509957375 138.85.151.208 52538 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:2711965314 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.125.1 52539 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:644386830 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.2.12 52540 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:3326468283 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.58.1 52541 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:617313365 2 tcp 1509957374 138.85.151.208 52542 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:2711965314 2 tcp 1509957374 192.168.125.1 52543 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:644386830 2 tcp 1509957374 192.168.2.12 52544 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:3326468283 2 tcp 1509957374 192.168.58.1 52545 typ host generation 0\r\na=ice-ufrag:root\r\na=ice-pwd:myreallysecretpassword\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtpmap:126 H264/90000\r\n",
    ReStr = "(.*)a=candidate.*host.*a=candidate.*host(.*)a=ice-ufrag.*a=setup:active(.*)a=mid:audio(.*)a=candidate.*host.*a=candidate.*host(.*)a=ice-ufrag.*a=setup:active(.*)a=mid:video(.*)",
    {ok, Pattern1} = re:compile(ReStr, [{newline, crlf}]),
    {Time1, _} = timer:tc(re, run, [ Sdp, Pattern1, [{capture,all_but_first,list}] ]),
    io:format("not using dotall, time is ~p~n", [Time1]),

    {ok, Pattern2} = re:compile(ReStr, [{newline, crlf}, dotall]),
    {Time2, _} = timer:tc(re, run, [ Sdp, Pattern2, [{capture,all_but_first,list}] ]),
    io:format("using dotall, time is ~p~n", [Time2]).
```

the run result:

```
101> tt:main3().
not using dotall, time is 4499
using dotall, time is 2760364
ok
```

From the result, we can find the difference is so large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally by default when `dotall` is not set then the `.` pattern does not match `\n` so the searching will only extend as far as the end of the line. When `dotall` is set the then `.` matches all characters until the end of the input string. This makes a difference in your case as your input string contains many lines.

The thing to remember is that `re` is based on [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) which follows the Perl regular expressions. One feature of these is that they are implemented using a back-tracking algorithm which means that when you have alternatives in your pattern, like for example `.*`, it results in a lot of searching to find a match. This is a property of Perl regular expressions and not due to bad implementation.

For a longer discussion on the various ways of implementing regular expressions see wikipedia [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (the third algorithm), [Implementing Regular Expressions](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/) by Russ Cox (the first paper), or Friedl's [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/book.html) (though he gives the 3 algorithms wrong names).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but how can i handle this situation, i need fast efficiency.

Comment: @BlackMamba You can't "handle the situation"; backtracking is expensive. If you've got a specific problem that needs to run fast, ask a new question about that.